# Assigning integers to dataframe fields ` OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C unsigned long`

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe `df` that looks like this:

```
                             var     val
    0            clump_thickness       5
    1             unif_cell_size       1
    2            unif_cell_shape       1
    3              marg_adhesion       1
    4     single_epith_cell_size       2
    5                bare_nuclei       1
    6                bland_chrom       3
    7              norm_nucleoli       1
    8                    mitoses       1
    9                      class       2
    11            unif_cell_size       4
    12           unif_cell_shape       4
    13             marg_adhesion       5
    14    single_epith_cell_size       7
    15               bare_nuclei      10
    17             norm_nucleoli       2
    20           clump_thickness       3
    25               bare_nuclei       2
    30           clump_thickness       6
    31            unif_cell_size       8
    32           unif_cell_shape       8
    34    single_epith_cell_size       3
    35               bare_nuclei       4
    37             norm_nucleoli       7
    40           clump_thickness       4
    43             marg_adhesion       3
    50           clump_thickness       8
    51            unif_cell_size      10
    52           unif_cell_shape      10
    53             marg_adhesion       8
    ...                      ...     ...
    204   single_epith_cell_size       5
    211           unif_cell_size       5
    215              bare_nuclei       7
    216              bland_chrom       7
    217            norm_nucleoli      10
    235              bare_nuclei  -99999
    257            norm_nucleoli       6
    324   single_epith_cell_size       8
```

I want to create a new column that holds the values of the `var` and `val` columns, converted to a number. I wrote the following code:

```
df['id'] = df.apply(lambda row: int.from_bytes('{}{}'.format(row.var, row.val).encode(), 'little'), axis = 1)
```

When I run this code I get the following error:

```
df['id'] = df.apply(lambda row: int.from_bytes('{}{}'.format(row.var, row.val).encode(), 'little'), axis = 1)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 4262, in apply
        ignore_failures=ignore_failures)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 4384, in _apply_standard
        result = Series(results)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 205, in __init__
        default=np.nan)
      File "pandas/_libs/src/inference.pyx", line 1701, in pandas._libs.lib.fast_multiget (pandas/_libs/lib.c:68371)
      File "pandas/_libs/src/inference.pyx", line 1165, in pandas._libs.lib.maybe_convert_objects (pandas/_libs/lib.c:58498)
    OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C unsigned long
```

I don't understand why. If I run

```
for column in df['var'].unique():
    for value in df['val'].unique():
        if int.from_bytes('{}{}'.format(column, value).encode(), 'little') > maximum:
            maximum = int.from_bytes('{}{}'.format(column, value).encode(), 'little')
        print(int.from_bytes('{}{}'.format(column, value), 'little'))
print()
print(maximum)
```

I get the following result:

```
    65731626445514392434127804442952952931
    67060854441299308307031611503233297507
    65731626445514392434127804442952952931
    68390082437084224179935418563513642083
    69719310432869140052839225623793986659
    73706994420223887671550646804635020387
    16399285238650560638676108961167827102819
    67060854441299308307031611503233297507
    72377766424438971798646839744354675811
    75036222416008803544454453864915364963
    69719310432869140052839225623793986659
    16399285238650560638676108961167827102819
    76365450411793719417358260925195709539
    68390082437084224179935418563513642083
    76365450411793719417358260925195709539
    73706994420223887671550646804635020387
    83632281929131549175300318205721294812263623257187
    71048538428654055925743032684074331235
    75036222416008803544454453864915364963
    72377766424438971798646839744354675811
    277249955343544548646026928445812341
    256480767909405238131904943128931957
    266865361626474893388965935787372149
    287634549060614203903087921104252533
    64059424565585367137514643836585471605
    261673064767940065760435439458152053
    282442252202079376274557424775032437
    .....
    60968996531299
    69179002195346541894528099
    58769973275747
    62068508159075
    59869484903523

    6026341019714892551838472781928948268513458935618931750446847388019
```

Based on these results I would say that the conversion to integers works fine. Furthermore, the largest created integer is not so big that it should cause problems when being inserted into the dataframe right?

**Question:** How can I successfully create a new column with the newly created integers? What am I doing wrong here?

**Edit:** Although bws's solution

```
  str(int.from_bytes('{}{}'.format(column, value).encode(), 'little'))
```

solves the error, I now have a new problem: the ids are all unique.. I don't understand why this happens but I suddenly have 3000 unique ids, while there are only 92 unique var/val combinations.

Answer (score 2):

I dont know the why. Maybe lamda use by default int in front of int64?
I have a workaround that maybe is useful for you.

Convert the result to string (*object*):`df['id'] = df.apply(lambda row: str(int.from_bytes('{}{}'.format(row["var"], row["val"]).encode(), 'little')), axis = 1)`

This is interesting to know: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.types.html

> uint64    Unsigned integer (0 to 18446744073709551615)

edit:

After read the last link I asume that when you use a loop, you are using the int python type, not the int that use pandas (come from numpy). So, when you work with a Dataframe you are using the types that numpy provide...

Int type from numpy come from *Object* so I think that the correct way to work with large integer is use *object*.

Its my conclusion but maybe I am wrong.

**Edit second question:**

Simple example works:

```
d2 = {'val': [2, 1, 1, 2],
 'var': ['clump_thickness', 'unif_cell_size', 'unif_cell_size', 'clump_thickness']
}

df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=d2)

df2['id'] = df2.apply(lambda row: str(int.from_bytes('{}{}'.format(row["var"], row["val"]).encode(), 'little')), axis = 1)
```

Result of df2:

```
print (df2)
   val              var                                      id
0    2  clump_thickness  67060854441299308307031611503233297507
1    1   unif_cell_size    256480767909405238131904943128931957
2    1   unif_cell_size    256480767909405238131904943128931957
3    2  clump_thickness  67060854441299308307031611503233297507
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Although it removes the initial error, I know have a different problem. I edited my question!

Comment: Works perfectly.